# How to customize text rendered in a `Gtk.TreeViewColumn`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk, pygobject

I have the file size in bytes stored in a `Gtk.ListStore` and want them to be rendered in a human-readable format by a `Gtk.CellRendererText`. Reading the documentation, it seems like `Gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_cell_data_func()` is the way to achieve this. Setting it up works without errors, but as soon as a cell is to be rendered, the whole application crashes after several failed assertions.

This is the code I'm using:

```
self._builder.get_object("ContentList.Size").set_cell_data_func(
    Gtk.CellRendererText(),
    self.render_formatted_size
)
```

And this is what's printed to *stderr*:

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py:44: Warning: g_object_freeze_notify: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return Gio.Application.run(self, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py:44: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return Gio.Application.run(self, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py:44: Warning: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return Gio.Application.run(self, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py:44: Warning: g_object_is_floating: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return Gio.Application.run(self, *args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py:44: Warning: g_object_get_qdata: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return Gio.Application.run(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Content of `self.render_formatted_size` should not matter here. It seems like it's never executed.

PS: Adding additional string columns to the model is not an option, as I want to be able to change display units (SI, IEC) at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a newly created CellRenderer, not an existing one. Something like this should be done instead:

```
rend = Gtk.CellRendererText()
column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("title", rend)
column.set_cell_data_func (rend, cell_fn, None);
tree.append_column(column)
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was helpful. It was not that I did not create an instance. As you can see there are `()` after `Gtk.CellRendererText` in my code. But thinking about the arguments you give to `Gtk.TreeViewColumn()`, I noticed I did not attach the renderer to the column I got from a `Gtk.Builder`. So now, after attaching it by calling `column.pack_start(rend)`, it works.